# How do I make line segments colored based on values in a data frame in rgl?

Tags: r, rgl

I am plotting line segments in 3d using the rgl package.  I want to color code the line segments based on a value in a dataframe not being plotted.  I can get the lines to be colored, however, each segment seems to be a gradient of colors.  How can I make each segment one solid color?Also, the lines are not colored based on the values in the dataframe I am trying to use.  My function works for scatterplots just fine but I am worried it can't translate to segments very well.   My code is posted below along with my test data.

```
library("rgl")
library("rglwidget")

zz <- "
sequence    x   y   z   x2  y2  z2  col
a   1   5   1   100 1000    2   4
b   2   4   1   200 900 2   3
c   2   4   1   300 800 2   2
d   2   4   1   400 700 2   1
e   3   3   1   500 600 2   0
f   3   3   1   600 500 2   -1
g   4   2   1   700 400 2   -2
h   4   2   1   800 300 2   -3
I   4   2   1   900 200 2   -4
j   5   1   1   1000    100 2   -5"


data <- read.table(text=zz, header=TRUE)

w <- names(data[8])

gradient <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"))

v <- gradient(10)[as.numeric(cut(data[[w]], breaks=10))]

segments3d(x=as.vector(t(log(data[,c(2,5)]))),
       y=as.vector(t(data[,c(4,7)])),
       z=as.vector(t(log(data[,c(3,6)]))),
       axes=FALSE, col=v, plot=TRUE)

rgl.bbox(color="grey50", emission="grey50",
     xat = log(10^((-1):6)), yat = c(1, 2, 3, 4), zat = log(10^((-1):6)), xlab=10^((-1):6), ylab = (1:4), zlab=10^((-1):6))

aspect3d(1,1,1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any case, you had better update `rgl` (The functions in the `rglwidget` package have been moved to `rgl`). `rgl` controls a color of a line by **"points"**. So you need to give a color twice per line.

```
x = as.vector(t(log(data[,c(2,5)])))
y = as.vector(t(data[,c(4,7)]))
z = as.vector(t(log(data[,c(3,6)])))
ind <- seq(2, 20, 2)

segments3d(x, y, z, axes = FALSE, col = rep(v, each = 2))
texts3d(x[ind], y[ind], z[ind], texts = data$sequence, col = v)
axes3d(xat = log(10^((-1):6)), yat = c(1, 2, 3, 4), zat = log(10^((-1):6)), 
       xlab = 10^((-1):6), ylab = (1:4), zlab = 10^((-1):6))
aspect3d(1, 1, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.  In another version of this code I use rglwidget because I use WebGL to create a web page with the graph.

Comment: You don't need the `rglwidget` package, it has been merged into `rgl`.